# How to get facebook group member count via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find Group Member Count by group id.
I am using the below Graph API to get group members to count, but in response, I am not getting member_count.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/group

Any suggestion,

Comment: Did you _ask_ for the field?

Comment: @CBroe I am asking for how to get member count of group member_count

Comment: And I am asking, whether you _asked for the field_ with the request that you made. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fields